# Why there are random data in AXI-LITE channels when a channel is not active?

Tags: axi

I have a simple FPGA design with following topology (on a xilinx FGPA device):

```
                                   axi-lite
[microblaze]----[axi interconnect]----------[uart16550]
                                      |
                                      |
                                     ila
```

The purpose was to use ILA to capture some AXI-LITE traffic, to learn how to use ILA as well as how axi-lite works (with regard to uart controller).

When examing the captured signal, I noticed that when the channels are not active (meaning that READY/VALID signal of the channel are not asserted at the same time), there are still some data appearing on the address/data signals of the channels. I was expecting that those signals are "inactive" (in the sense that they keep at constant values). So I am wondering, why there are random data flowing on those signals, and where it comes from?

The following is a screen short for write channels, captured when I echo "hello" to the serial port.

[image: screen shot of ILA captured signal]

PS: I consulted a collegue (front-end designer), he said that probably this is because the address/data signals from AXI-Lite master are directly coming out from comb-logic (i.e., not latched in register) to AXI-Lite slave, and the comb-logic is also involved with other logic thus its output keep changing and get reflected on AXI signals even when the AXI-lite channels are not active.

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. There's no particular reason to hold them constant, and it saves logic. I wouldn't be surprised if the address signals are common between the read and write channels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate a bit on this, particularly on why it saves logic? I know that my expectation were wrong, and there must be some thing I am not aware of...

Comment: As I suggested, there's no need to have separate registers for read addresses and write addresses. You simply have one address register, and wire it to the address lines for both the AXI write address channel and the AXI read address channel.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see what you mean by "save logic" (i.e., use the same register(s) for read and write addresses). I was assuming it has something to do with my original question (why the address and data signals change "randomly" in non-active state...).